# Efficiently parse a string representing a list of floats to a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

The input is a string representing a list of floats, including `nan` values. I want to parse this to make a list of these numbers as strings.

```py
input = '[12,2,4,nan,0]'
output = ['12','2','4','nan','0']
```

One option is `yaml.safe_load()`, But it's too slow. I am looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: input is string not list.

Comment: One solution is also try to call `re.findall(r'[^,\[\]]+', input)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you want exactly, but I'd do it like this.

```
output = input[1:-1].split(",")
```

Comment: Should be `input[1:-1].split(',')` to remove the `[` and `]` from the string, instead of removing the first and last result from the list. This is probably the best solution if the list is known to contain only valid floats with no whitespace.

Comment: @kaya3 That was what I meant, thanks for correcting me.